# Word 2016 - Table of Figures Missing Entries

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have a large word document with quite a few tables and figures. I have created a List of Tables and a List of Figures, but both of them are missing quite a few captions. For each Figure and Table, I used the add caption function. It appears that they are only listing captions from the first 8 sections, or about 15 pages. Everything after that is being ignored.

I have checked to make sure that all of the captions are not inserted in-line or in a text box. At this point I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried pressing Ctrl+A and then F9 to update all fields, selecting Update entire table? If that doesn't work, and you're sure the captions were added correctly, the only thing I can think of that would limit a TOC (incl. Table of figures\Table of tables) to a specific section is a \b switch in the field code. Did you manually build the tables or use the button on the References tab? Does your doc contain bookmarks, and, if you select the whole Table of figures (or tables), right-click, and click Toggle Field Codes, do the TOC fields contain a '\b' followed by the name of a bookmark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Another project member had created the later captions and had replaced the auto-incrementing numbers with his own.

He did this because the formatting for the headers had not been set up yet which caused the numbers for the captions to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I took these steps to solve this problem

1. Select the Table of contents (table of figures, list of tables)
2. Right-click on the selection
3. Select "Update Fileds" on the pop menu
4. Select "Update page numbers only"/"Update entire table" as the case might be.

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be that Track Formatting is on, and some changes are not accepted. Accept all changes and try updating the fields again.

Answer (score 1):

In body of report click on your Table title.
References > Insert Caption

Label (whatever it is a Figure, Table, etc.)

Position (above selected item)

Exclude label from caption (uncheck)

Numbering (change based on what you need, for example I need to check include chapter number)
click OK

Scroll back up to your TOC, Right Click and Update entire Field (or Ctrl+A & F9). That table should now show up in your list.

Answer (score 0):

same problem here ...then I finally realized what I was doing wrong... you need to insert each new set of tables(or figures) separately using the References/ Insert Table of Figures/label tabs...